# .htaccess rewrite rule for two GET variables on index.php?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to do a rewrite but I couldn't find it or do it myself.

I'm trying to convert

`http://www.homepage.com/variable1/variable2` to `http://www.homepage.com/index.php?var1=variable1&var2=variable2` or `http://www.homepage.com/?var1=variable1&var2=variable2`

I have tried

- `RewriteRule    ^/(.*)/(.*)$  ?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]`
- `RewriteRule    ^(.*)/(.*)$  ?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]`
- `RewriteRule    ^/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]`
- `RewriteRule    ^(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]`

none of these worked. What am I doing wrong? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]
```

You didn't put / before index.php.