# .htaccess rewrite rule for one GET variables on index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite, indexing

.htaccess rewrite rule for one GET variables on index.php?

I know how works for 2 variables

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]
```

[.htaccess rewrite rule for two GET variables on index.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630676/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-two-get-variables-on-index-php)

how just for one??? index.php?var1=$1

Comment: I don't understand why you ask. Is it so difficult to simplify that for one variable ?

Comment: It's not that easy with the same example. Because you have to test the existence of the file to avoid any loop problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

Comment: For me works that in .htaccess

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?id=$1

Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. There is not much difference: Mine means: not `/`. Yours means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. There are some characters that will accept mine and not yours (like `.`).